# What are Katarina's abilities' damage type?

Tags: league-of-legends

Do Katarina's abilities do physical or magical damage?

Physical damage is reduced by armor, while magical damage is reduced by magic resistance.

Comment: Gah.  Please rephrase the question a bit.  I don't quite understand

Comment: He wants to know if Katarina's abilities do physical or magical damage. Physical damage is reduced by armor, while magical damage is reduced by magic resistance.

Comment: @Mechko he's using jargon.  Most LoL players should be able to parse it.

Comment: @tzenes lol ok.  I looked at it and thought "English parser detects crash imminent"

Comment: He was missing "do" at the beginning of the question

Comment: It is nice to see this many people collaborate. =). Sorry for not expressing myself clearly. It is as Matthew stated.

Comment: LoL Seigo.  Welcome to Gaming.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Katarina's abilities](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Katarina/Ability_Details) break down as follows:

- (Q) Bouncing Blade - Magic (Both initial hit and the damage from consumed mark)
- (W) Sinister Steel - Magic
- (E) Shunpo - Magic
- (R) Death Lotus - Magic

All are magic damage. Do not confuse this with the fact that some abilities scale off AD and AP

Comment: Thanks! It is as I imagined.. so it justifies the importance of sorcerer`s shoes for the magic penetration.

Comment: where do you find these information? I think RIOT should somehow provide these info. I often find myself stuck while choosing armor late game

Comment: @nimcap google?  I found it across a couple sources as no one source gave me all the information.

Comment: I tried googling lots of times, I never found a source that contains all of the skills and their types. I wish RIOT added that information in game.

Comment: @nimcap when you pick a character the tooltip says what kind of damage the skills do. i mean ingame, not while chosing

Comment: It has been long time since I played LoL. Maybe they have added that feature in the new versions.

Comment: http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Katarina_the_Sinister_Blade
Has all the champions, and descriptions of each ability.